# Adding conditions to python function `set_partitions`

Tags: python, arrays, function, sorting, conditional-statements

I want to work with a given group of elements and reorder them as the function `set_partitions` do but adding a condition to this lists, I will try to explain my problem in a understandable and simple way. A example of how this function works,

```
from more_itertools import set_partitions

a=[1,2,3]

print(list(set_partitions(a)))
```

And return the possible agrupations,

```
[[[1,   2,   3]], 
 [[1], [2,   3]],
 [[1,   2], [3]],
 [[2], [1,   3]],
 [[1], [2], [3]]]
```

I want to put a constrain in this function (for example could be, the groups created need to sum a even number). I can simply extract the arrays and apply the constrains, but my problem is that I need to do it for a huge number of list elements, and my computer dies before finishing. If I apply the constrain directly to the function `set_partitions` the problem will be reduced because the constrain applied is very strong, i mean, for example it reduce a total amount of 4213597 million possible combinations to 12k valid combinations (but i can not go further because of memory problems), so applying the condition will solve the problem.

For this I need to understand the function `set_partitions`, this function can be used only copying the following code without needing other auxiliar functions, or to import anything,

```
def set_partitions(iterable, k=None):

    L = list(iterable)
    n = len(L)

    def set_partitions_helper(L, k):
        n = len(L)
        if k == 1:
            yield [L]
        elif n == k:
            yield [[s] for s in L]
            
        else:
            
            e, *M = L
            
            for p in set_partitions_helper(M, k - 1):
                yield [[e], *p]
                
            for p in set_partitions_helper(M, k):
                
                for i in range(len(p)):
                    yield p[:i] + [[e] + p[i]] + p[i + 1 :]

    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        yield from set_partitions_helper(L, k)
```

I' have experience programming and is my work but I do not arrive to this level, so there is some things in the function that I do not understand, as for example what is doing,
`e, *M = L` or the following elements in the helper function.

I need some help understanding how work this function for finding **where the condition can be placed**.

Thanks a lot!

Addition explaining my specific case:

The elements I'm trying to group  in partitions are matrixes in tensorial product, for example chains of fixed lenght for example,

[image]

A element will be a chain of this style, that we can represent as a string,

`'xz11y'`

I want the elements of the subgroups to commute, `1` commute with everything, `x/y/z` only commutes with itself (and the identity), so we need to compare the chains only, so for example if we have the 3 matrixes,

`['1z'],['zz'],['x1']`

A valid agrupation will be

`'1z','zz' | 'x1'`

Because `'1z'` commutes with `zz`.

A invalid agrupation will be

`'1z' | 'zz', 'x1'`

Because `'zz'` and `'x1'` have a x and a z in same position, and this operators do not commute.

This is simplified, so I have a Hamiltonian of about 19 or more separate operators of this type and I need to find the agrupations that conserve this commutation.

Comment: `a, b = p` is called "unpacking". If `p` has two elements, then `a` is set to `p`'s first element, and `b` to `p`'s second element. If `p` had three element sinstead of 2, you could write `a, b, c = p`. If `p` had four elements, you could write `a, b, c, d = p`. But if you don't know or don't care about `p`'s number of elements, you can write: `a, *r = p`. Now `a` is set to `p`'s first element, then `r` is set to *the list of all remaining elements in `p`*.

Comment: What's the condition?? If it really reduces the number of combinations from 4 million millions to just 27, then surely there can be much more efficient code than modifying `set_partitions`, but we can't help you until you actually tell us the condition.

Comment: Note that `set_partitions` is a generator function, not a function that returns a list. If `cond` is a function that returns True or False, you can use `filter` to discard the elements you're not interesting in without storing them in memory: `for x in filter(cond, set_partitions(L)): print(x)`. Or alternatively: `for x in set_partitions(L); if cond(x): print(x)`. The important thing here is to ***not*** call `list` on the result of `set_partitions`.

Comment: About the condition: I'm working with a set of matrixes of tensorial products that can be expressed with strings '1zx1' means pauli matrixes in the respective site, 1 means the identity. I only want to create subsets where all the elements commute, and this can be reduced to compare this strings, knowing 1 commutes with everyone, x/y/z commutes with x/y/z, but x do not commute with y or z. My bad but is not reduced only to 27, I had an error in the code but the reduction is from 4 million to 12k   @Stef. Anyway I will try what you said in the last comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Stef It worked!, Now the program runs for a long long time, but as is not writting in memory is no problem!  Thank you so much for the help I wasted many hours trying to solve the problem! :)

Comment: can you please explain the problem in more detail? I'm sure there is a more efficient way to generate your matrices or strings but I'm not sure I understood the problem statement clearly.

Comment: @Stef I explained a bit with more detail at the end of the question. Thanks